# How to setup Cron Job with Google App in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-datastore

I have a google app that is functioning as a blog, and am wanting to use a cron job to send posts to subscribers weekly. I am, however, confused on how exactly they work. I'm using Google's User Service to sign people in, and datastore to store posts. Aside from a cron.xml that defines the service to do and the URL , what else do I need to put in the code to make it work? Additionally, could I make the URL point to a function that goes through all the posts in the datastore and emails the subscriber?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can think of a cron job in AppEngine as a periodical GET request to a servlet. So what you need to do is:

1. Create a servlet, and add your desired code into the doGet() function. In your case, you need to query your dababase, go through the posts, and send them to your user.
2. Add your servlet definition into web.xml, let's assume the path of this servlet is `/servlet/sendPosts`
3. Add a new cron configuration section to cron.xml, it will look like below:

> ```
> <cron>
>     <url>/servlet/sendPosts</url>
>     <description>Send posts to user every week</description>
>     <schedule>every monday 08:30</schedule>
>     <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
>   </cron>
> ```